# validate group radio button

Tags: javascript, html

i have designed page
that contains 60 questions and each question have 5 radio button.
i want to validate all of question; in other mean all of them had to answer.
and if one of them is not answered tell the number of it yo the user.
how i can validate it with javascript
here is some example of code

```
<div  >
  <tr id="trr1" onmouseover="changecolor('tr1','trr1')" onmouseout="backcolor('tr1','trr1')" >
    <td colspan="5">1. question 1</td>
    </tr>
  <tr id="tr1"  onmouseover="changecolor('tr1','trr1')" onmouseout="backcolor('tr1','trr1')">
    <td>totaly agree <input id="s1" name="s1" type="radio" value="2" /></td>
    <td>agree <input id="s1" name="s1" type="radio" value="1" /></td>
    <td>none <input id="s1" name="s1" type="radio" value="0" /></td>
    <td>dis-agree <input id="s1" name="s1" type="radio" value="-1" /></td>
    <td>totaly dis-agree <input id="s1" name="s1" type="radio" value="-2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trr2" onmouseover="changecolor('tr2','trr2')" onmouseout="backcolor('tr2','trr2')" >
    <td colspan="5">2. question 2</td>
    </tr>
  <tr id="tr2"  onmouseover="changecolor('tr2','trr2')" onmouseout="backcolor('tr2','trr2')">
    <td>totaly agree <input id="s2" name="s2" type="radio" value="2" /></td>
    <td>agree <input id="s2" name="s2" type="radio" value="1" /></td>
    <td>none <input id="s2" name="s2" type="radio" value="0" /></td>
    <td>dis-agree<input id="s2" name="s2" type="radio" value="-1" /></td>
    <td>totaly dis-agree <input id="s2" name="s2" type="radio" value="-2" /></td>
  </tr>
 </div>
```

Comment: this link should help you learn to validate a form using JavaScript:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806594/javascript-form-onsubmit-handling

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding jQuery and using the [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/). It's a much more convenient way to deal with this type of tasks. Forcing to choose one option will be as simple as:

```
radioGroup: {required :true}
```

Overriding message with error to inform user about not picking anything:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
  required: "This field is required."
});
```